# Gradle get other project jar file path

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I am trying to add a task to a multi-project build to copy the Gradle-generated jar file from a different subproject in some location. I tried this:

```
task createClientJar(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'jar') {
  from(project(':other').libsDirName 
    + project(':other').tasks.jar.archivePath)
  into rootProject.file('libs/unmanaged')
}
```

However I get the following:

```
> Could not find property 'jar' on task set.
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the project doesn't have a task named `jar`, e.g. because it doesn't have the `java` plugin applied.

Comment: Turns out it doesn't find `:other:jar`, most likely because that project's build script is only evaluated after the current build script. Although there is an ugly workaround for this, reaching out into the project model of another project is problematic and discouraged. In the case at hand, you should probably be using project dependencies instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add ':other:jar' to:

```
task createClientJar(type: Copy, dependsOn: ':other:jar') {
...
}
```

and it will work! For more info https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html